# Distribution of pixel intensity in percentage plot

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I am trying to plot the pixel intensity in percentage of a gray scale image. I have done the preprocessing part of scaling and equalization of the gray image.

I know he histogram plot gives the pixel intensity distribution along the Y axis but i want that in percentage.

Any help is appreciated.

The code i used is here

```
  clc;
    close all;
    clear all;
    I=imread('sand5.jpg');
    j=rgb2gray(I);
    figure,imshow(j);
    J=scale_image(j,1);
    figure,imshow(J);
    K=histeq(J);
    figure,imshow(K);
```

I need the plot for Pixel intensity distribution in percentage VS pixel intensity values(0-255) along x axis for the gray scale image.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute the histogram

```
nn = hist( K(:), 0:255 ); % histogram for 0..255 bins
```

Now `nn` counts the **number** of pixels at each bin. To get the percentage you only need to divide by the total number of pixels (`numel(K)`) and multiply by 100.

```
figure;
bar( 0:255, nn*numel(K)/100 );
title('pixel intensity distribution (%)');
xlabel('intensity level');
ylabel('%');
```